# Polynomial coefficients in subfield if all evaluations in subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, extension-field

I'm reading through a proof on central simple algebras and the following seems to be implicitly assumed:

> Let $L/K$ be a field extension, $F \in L[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ a
>   polynomial such that $F(k_1, \ldots, k_n) \in K$ for all $(k_1, \ldots, k_n) \in K^n$. Then the coefficients of $F$ actually lie in $K$.

Is this true in the form stated above, or under additional assumptions? In the proof I am reading, $F$ is homogeneous and $L/K$ is a finite extension.

Comment: There is a problem with the finite fields. For $\alpha\in\mathbb F_4\setminus\mathbb F_2$ we have that $\alpha X+\alpha X^2$ does not belong to $\mathbb F_2[X]$.

Comment: If $K$ is infinite, then try to show the general result for $n=1$. (This is easily enough.) Then use induction on $n$.

Comment: Btw, Lagrange's interpolation solves the problem in characteristic zero.

Comment: Hint: interpolate (or CRT) and induct. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $K$ to be the field with $p$ elements, $p$ a prime, $L$ to be the field with $p^{2}$ elements, and let $\alpha \in L \setminus K$.

The polynomial
$$F = \alpha (X^{p} - X)$$
is identically zero for all evaluations of $X$ in $F$. But clearly $F \notin K[X]$.

But then perhaps you are working in characteristic zero? Or, as suggested by user26857, $K$ is infinite?

Comment: The case where $K$ is finite is not explicitly excluded from the theorem, but I guess I can leave it out since finite fields have trivial Brauer group and studying the latter is the main goal of the course. Still, it sort of annoys me that this was not mentioned in the course. I will try to write out a proof in the case $K$ is infinite with user26857's hints.

Comment: @Bib-lost, yes, you have received some excellent hints!

Comment: Do you also believe that we can drop the assumption that $K$ is infinite when we demand that $F$ be homogeneous? I have found a proof in the case $K$ is infinite, but it would definitely be more desirable to have a proof that always works.

Comment: Even when $F$ is homogeneous, you would have polynomials like $\alpha(X^{p} Y - X Y^{p})$.

Comment: @Bib-lost, thx.

Answer (score 1):

A proof of the following statement:

> Let $K$ be a field, $L/K$ a field extension. Let $F \in L[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ be a polynomial such that $F(k_1, \ldots, k_n) \in K$ for all $(k_1, \ldots, k_n) \in K^n$ and $\deg(F) < \lvert K \rvert$. Then the coefficients of $F$ lie in $K$.

By induction on $n$. If $n=0$ then $F$ is a constant polynomial and there is nothing to show. We consider the case $n=1$. Let 
$$
F(X) = \sum_{i=0}^d g_iX^i
$$
where $d = \deg(F) < \lvert K \rvert$ and $g_0, \ldots, g_d \in L$. We can use Lagrange interpolation (user26857 mentioned that this works when the characteristic is 0, but I only need that $d < \lvert K \rvert$). Indeed, just pick different elements $x_0, \ldots, x_d \in K$ and define the polynomial
$$
l_j(X) = \prod_{m=0, m \neq j}^d \frac{X - x_m}{x_j - x_m} \in K[X]
$$
for $j \in \lbrace 0, \ldots, d\rbrace$. $l_j$ is a degree $d$ polynomial and one has $l_j(x_i) = \delta_{i, j}$. Because the degree $d$ polynomial
$$
F(X) - \sum_{j=0}^d F(x_j) l_j(X)
$$
has at least $d+1$ distinct roots (namely $x_0, \ldots, x_d$) the polynomial must be identically zero. Hence we find that
$$
F(X) = \sum_{j=0}^d F(x_j) l_j(X) \in K[X]
$$
which concludes the proof in the case $n = 1$.

Suppose now $n > 1$, write
$$
F(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = \sum_{i=0}^d F_i(X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1})X_n^i
$$
with $d = \deg(F) < \lvert K \rvert$ and $F_i \in L[X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}]$ with $\deg(F_i) \leq d$. This time we argue via contraposition. If not all coefficients of $F$ lie in $K$, then pick $i_0 \in \lbrace 0, 1, \ldots, d \rbrace$ such that the coefficients of $F_{i_0}$ do not all lie in $K$. By induction hypothesis we can pick $(k_1, \ldots, k_{n-1}) \in K^{n-1}$ such that $F_{i_0}(k_1, \ldots, k_{n-1}) \not\in K$. Then not all coefficients of the polynomial in one variable
$$
G(X) = \sum_{i=0}^d g_iX^i
$$
where $g_i = F_i(k_1, \ldots, k_{n-1})$ lie in $K$. By the case $n=1$ this implies that $G(k_n) \not\in K$ for some $k_n \in K$. Hence $F(k_1, \ldots, k_n) \not\in K$. $\square$

Comment: Good job! +1...